# What is the English idiom about "expensive" that expresses the idea that "It is so expensive that you feel like you got ripped-off"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Ok, if I say "*this car is too expensive*" or "*this car is very expensive*", then I can not express the connotation of "*expensive*".

However, if I say "*this car is damn expensive*" then I better convey the connotation of "*expensive*".

So my question is:

What is the English idiom about "*expensive*" that expresses the idea that "*It is so expensive that you feel like you got ripped-off and/or overcharged and/or unmeaningfully expensive*"?

For example, "*damn expensive*" could be ok but is there any other term?

Comment: If you just want to convey the idea that it isn't worth the price, you can say, "this car is over-priced" or "they want too much for it" This can be said whether the car is priced at $1000 and is only worth $500 or if it's priced at $200,000.00 and is only worth $175,000.00.

Comment: I'm confused by this question. It seems to want an idiom for "a rip-off", i.e. "too expensive". But "rip-off" *is* an idiom meaning "too expensive". So you're looking for an idiom of an idiom?

Comment: I have no idea how “damn expensive” expresses any connotation of _expensive_ that “very expensive” doesn't. Like Andy, I don't understand  what you're looking for at all here.

Comment: To keep it simple, *overpriced* has obvious meaning.

Comment: @AndyT That there's an anti-idiom. A phrase that means exactly what it says.

Comment: Yeah, what's wrong with _this car is a rip-off_?

Comment: It needs to be noted that an item may be exceptionally expensive, yet both the price and the expenditure may be well-justified.  This is different from a "rip-off" where the price has been inflated somehow, or a simple poor-choice purchase, where the buyer may have spent more than he needed to.

Comment: @Jim Why not make *overpriced* an answer?  I always wonder why people bury the best answers in the comments.

Comment: Unrealistically priced? Aggressively priced?

Comment: "Damn expensive" absolutely doesn't imply to me that I'd be ripped off if I buy it, just that it's, well, damn expensive. A private jet is damn expensive, but if I were the sort of rich bastard who could afford a private jet, I wouldn't necessarily feel like I was getting ripped off, unless I could find a similar private jet for cheaper.

Comment: There's a difference between expensive and a rip-off. For example, if you are walking to a football game, and someone sells you a program for $2. Then, walking a bit further on, the exact same program is being sold by a different person for $1. "What a rip-off!", you think to yourself, "That first vendor cheated me!". However the program was not expensive.

Comment: **Highly related,** if not exact duplicates: [Highway robbery](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134086) | [Very expensive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269707)

Comment: Sometimes we refer to such things as "gold-plated".

Comment: user1 - it's extremely unlikely you are using the word "idiom" incorrectly. do some research on what "idiom" means.

Comment: eye-wateringly expensive, daylight robbery, extortionate

Comment: The phrase 'cheap at half the price' is commonly heard in the UK these days: an inversion of the expression of good value 'cheap at twice the price'.

Comment: Does `Ovrepriced` work?

Comment: @JHCL I live in the UK and I don't think I've ever heard somebody say "cheap at half the price", so it's not that common. Could be a regional or generational thing. It's also total nonsense if it's supposed to mean that something is overpriced.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23932/what-on-earth-does-cheap-at-half-the-price-mean

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I too live in the UK and have heard (and used) 'cheap at half the price' many times to mean (counter-intuitively) 'that is good value for money'... However I have *never* heard JHCL's 'cheap at twice the price'...

Comment: I think a post which has received 19+ answers is a post which has been adequately answered. Most of the new answers being suggested are not really related to being "ripped off" or "cheated" or "swindled".

Comment: I vote to reopen  this question, which is no unclear!

Comment: Suggested fix: [**unnecessarily expensive**](https://www.google.it/search?q=unnecessarily+expensive&oq=unnecessarily+expensive&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22unnecessarily+expensive%22)

Comment: @Josh61 which is "no unclear"?? In any case you know full well that not all VTC may be in common agreement, perhaps two believed the OP was opinion based, and 1 thought it too broad. I haven't checked yet. However, it's not as if the OP hasn't accepted an answer, he /she did days ago! And I'll repeat the comment I made previously, recent answers are off the track, they don't add anything interesting, curious, original you fill in the missing adjective.

Comment: Although "unnecessarily expensive" is very subjective. I might feel an antique object is worth its price tag because I appreciate its beauty, its history, the craftsmanship behind it, I could also consider it as being an investment. In that case, I am willing to spend a "small fortune" on it. Another person might think it unnecessarily expensive for what it represents e.g. a [porcelain vase](https://www.google.it/search?q=porcelain+vase&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCEQsARqFQoTCMPu_pDT68cCFUI6GgodlyoOkQ&biw=1366&bih=677), a .wooden table ...

Comment: @Mari-LouA - do you really think this question is unclear? The accepted answer got 72 upticks , and the first 5 answers a total of 214 upticks..just for answering to an unclear question?  A few late confused answers don't prove much. It should have been  a good and useful collection of terms  and idioms related to the subject.....

Comment: @Josh61 did I VTC the question? But I tell you something "rip off" is an idiom, and it expresses perfectly the OP's request. In that sense the question is unclear. Secondly, how can you have an idiom for an idiom (rip off)? I think this part is quite confusing. See first few comments above. 2. "It should have been" Why, isn't it a good collection *now*?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**exorbitant** is also used for extremely unreasonable prices.

An example of using it, quoting the Oxford dictionary:

> some hotels charge exorbitant rates for phone calls

Comment: I love the word exorbitant because it's etymology translates it to "off of course", and if you bring the broken down parts into modern English first it literally means "outside of orbit" pricing, which is a wonderful inference.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question, which is not unclear!

Comment: Seems my comment that pointed out *exorbitant is not an English idiom* has been deleted... strange. I did not know valid comments could be deleted... :/ Ok, then.

Comment: I always thought the origin of the word "exorbitant" was "enough to make your eyes pop out of their sockets (orbits)"

Answer (score 51):

***[Pay through the nose](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+through+the+nose)*** is another common expression:

> - Pay an excessive amount for something, as in:  *We paid through the nose for that vacation.*
>
>   - *The origin of this term has been lost. Possibly it alludes to the Danish nose tax, imposed in Ireland in the 9th century, whereby delinquent taxpayers were punished by having their noses slit. [Second half of 1600s]*

(AHD)

Comment: is this idiom used commonly? I have never heard it?

Comment: Yes, it is a common expression.

Comment: Is it commonly used in US too? I just said that to my friend who lives there and he didn't recognize it at all. In fact, he though it would mean that something was cheap, because one could pay for it with boogers, instead of real money (both being green, in his mind).

Comment: Yes, it's common in the US as well.

Comment: I have heard this in the US, but not nearly as frequently as something costing an arm and a leg. Neither expression directly means you got ripped off, just that you paid a lot, but pay through the nose is closer to being ripped off though. Context is really important in the use of these expressions to signify whether you just splurged or feel taken advantage of. As I side note, I personally use exorbitant the most as opposed to an the idioms.

Comment: @jdfLemon: I agree that the "arm and a leg" idiom just means it was expensive; there's no implication of a rip-off there. But I do think "pay through the nose" expressly implies overcharging. You don't ever pay through the nose willingly, but you may pay and arm and a leg for something you really, really wanted.

Comment: I think this is the strongest idiom to fit the request, but for the "single-word" tag.

Answer (score 39):

Native speakers will often use the word 'Extortionate'. Literally, this is saying that the seller or vendor etc was trying to extort the money out of you, but in this figurative sense it really just means it was so expensive you feel like you were ripped off or taken advantage off.

> The entrance fee was extortionate

Comment: For what it's worth I have never heard of this word until now... is exorbitant not more common?

Comment: Nope, definitely extortionate, from the verb to extort, and I hear and use it regularly. It's possible, though, that it's specific to British English or is even a colloquialism specific to a region of the UK.

Comment: I've never heard this in the US

Comment: Ah, I'm simply from the colonies. :p

Comment: Definitely makes it into the Oxford and Collins dictionaries and is synonymous with exorbitant. Which is good, because you guys had me wondering if I'd misheard for the last few decades! http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/extortionate

Comment: The closest I've come to that is: "$25 to get in?!?  That's extortion."

Comment: Funny, must be in British English, in the US I have never heard extortionate!

Comment: I'm from California, I've definitely heard extortionate. Similar, but not the same as exorbitant - that just means absurdly high, extortionate means high because they have a monopoly or close enough, and can and do charge whatever the crap they feel like. More negative a connotation. Not terribly *common* a word, but definitely a word.

Comment: Yeah it's used in the same way and with the same result, but is a completely different ... Image? Personally I think extortionate is more colourful, although implies someone is profiting from you which exorbitant doesn't necessarily do

Comment: (+1) This literally answers the OP's question, in that it fits precisely "so expensive it feels as if you are being ripped off".

Comment: I have both heard it and used it myself, and I'm from the US.

Comment: As @Jim says, I am from the northeastern US and have heard the phrase "That's extortion!" but never the adjectival form "That's extortionate!". It would be like if you told me that there was an adjective form for "robbery", say "robberiffic": it makes sense that you could then have "highway-robberiffic prices" but it just sounds weird because I've never heard that particular form.

Comment: @neminem Sure, it’s a word; I doubt many Americans would fail to understand it, considering *extort*. We’d get it. It’s just not the thing that would come to mind, I’d think. Don’t hear it nearly as much as *exorbitant*.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question, which is not unclear !

Comment: @Josh61 - this is an answer, not a question

Comment: You can vote to reopen the question if you like.

Answer (score 28):

A common expression is to say something "*costs an arm and a leg*" to confer the connotation of it being a rip-off, or overpriced, or just very expensive.

Comment: This doesn't imply a rip-off to me though, just something that is super expensive, even rightly so.

Comment: I'd argue that your half right, and half wrong. I think it more means that it is super expensive relative to what it is. "Paying through the nose" is certainly a much better idiom.

Comment: see Martha's comment above, if you haven't already

Answer (score 26):

What about being "[gouged](https://www.google.com/search?q=gouged&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)"? That is common a common euphemistic verb for charging or being charged exorbitant prices.

> gouge (v.) 1560s, "to cut with a gouge," from gouge (n.). Meaning "to force out with a gouge" (especially of the eyes, in fighting) attested by 1800. Meaning "to swindle" is American English colloquial from 1826 (implied in plural noun gougers). Related: Gouged; gouging.

<sup>Source: [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gouge)</sup>

Comment: Can you expand your answer by including what it means?

Comment: In this case, the expression" to be gouged" seems to come from the wood working tool, a gouge. It is a curved chisel used to remove significant, or excess amounts of material (also leaving behind hat's known as a "gouge" in the rough form). If you feel you are gouged in a financial transaction, it is as if excessive amounts of material (ie: money) are being removed from your wallet.

Comment: "Price gouging" is a pretty popular term. Especially right after 9/11 when gas prices went through the roof, a lot of unsavory gas stations were doing some sort of illegal things with their prices. Not entirely sure how, but I know that a lot of state Attorney Generals were getting involved and there were hotlines for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 17):

*Robbery* is arguably a more common expression than *exorbitant*.

[Robbery](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/robbery) (in ODO) carries the definition:

> Unashamed swindling or overcharging

It is often used in this context with the prefixes *highway* or *daylight*.

[*Daylight robbery*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/daylight-robbery?q=daylight+robbery) and [highway robbery](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/highway-robbery?q=highway+robbery) (in ODO) both carry this definition:

> Blatant and unfair overcharging

For example, you could say:

> You're selling me this car at £5000? That's daylight robbery.

Comment: If you're looking for a phrase - "highway robbery" - as there's nothing quite as irritating as getting robbed on the highway. Well, the origin of the phrase would have been from a time when being on a highway you were the most exposed to thieves and because you were a long way from a source of help, they could rob you badly.

Comment: Daylight robbery is a common UK English idiom.

Comment: I think including daylight or highway help as on its own `robbery` could imply violence was used

Comment: As an American I've never heard the term "daylight robbery". Highway, yes.

Comment: *Daylight robbery* is used all the time in the UK to indicate something being overpriced, when you have no real choice due to a situational monopoly, for example you are visiting a fayre or a stadium or a festival and the price of a beer is three times what it would be elsewhere but you have no choice if you want one to shop around as you have paid to enter the area. While it is legal, it feels like robbery performed 'during the day' i.e. in a situation that a robbery would not normally occur.

Comment: Highway robbery does not fit here, it's a literal act and has no relevance to being overpriced.

Comment: I've used "highway robbery" in this context before, but definitely less often than *arm and a leg* or *pay through the nose*

Comment: I vote to  reopen this question,which is not unclear.

Answer (score 8):

"[They saw you coming](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/They+must+have+seen+you+coming)" - this is used in particular when saying that someone else was ripped off.

They must have seen you coming:,

> - You were really cheated. They saw you coming and decided they could cheat you easily.
>
>   - *Andy: it cost two hundred dollars. Rachel: You paid two hundred dollars for that thing? Boy, they must have seen you coming. Bob: Do you think I paid too much for this car? It's not as good as I thought it was. Tom: It's almost a wreck. They must have seen you coming.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms)

- Another one would be "[hosed](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hosed)". As in: "We were totally hosed on the purchase of this useless car."

(Urban Dictionary)

Comment: You don't need another person to be involved to use this colorful expression.  "Can you believe I paid $x for it?  They must have really seen me coming."

Comment: The implication is that it is an insult. Yes, someone can insult themselves if they choose.

Comment: It could be said in a playful way.

Comment: Indeed, I try to playfully insult myself as often as possible.

Comment: nice idiom, good one

Comment: I think "soaked" is another one similar to "hosed."

Answer (score 8):

[fleece](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fleece)

*v.*

> to cheat, swindle or strip of money

to charge excessively for goods or services

The idiom has its origins in sheering wool from sheep, also known as their "fleece" (*n.*), which is such a dramatic change in a sheep's appearance, so also is the metaphor intended to convey a likewise dramatic change for the consumer.

e.g.

The car salesmen at Empire Cars are unethical; they *fleece* all of their customers.

Answer (score 5):

The following words synonyms of "excessive" were not yet mentioned:

**outrageous, exagerated, extravagant, prohibitive, sky high** may apply to the car price and **unaffordable** to the car.

*EDIT*: I have forgotten **astronomical**, **skyrocketing**, **staggering** and **obscene**

Comment: I would give the bounty to "This mountain bike was **outrageously** expensive."

Answer (score 5):

Can you believe I paid $x for this mountain bike? **I feel like I've been had**  or **I think I've been had**.

(Which means, I feel as though I've been taken advantage of).

Comment: an excellent idiom...

Answer (score 3):

[gyp](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gyp&allowed_in_frame=0)

> "to cheat, swindle," 1889, American English, probably derived from the colloquial shortening of *Gypsy* (compare *gip*). Related: *Gypped*. As a noun, "fraudulent action, a cheat," by 1914.

e.g.

- I thought it was a good deal at first, but I had to pay extra for rustproofing, the extended warranty, and a list of hidden costs, and it broke down as soon as I drove it a block, so basically my new car was a complete *gyp*.
- Whomever posted this request for an **idiom**, and tagged the request **"single-word,"** got *gypped* on the responses.

Comment: This term has fallen out of use, and was never actually politically correct to use, but it was common. Today, *gyp* is recognized as a racist term. Just answering the question, and I meant no offense to our wandering friends, but we understand they don't like it.

Comment: I have never heard tis used as a racist term?  it's totally commonplace in BrE.  "You got gypped!"  I had no idea it came from "gypsy"

Comment: The use of 'gyp' is quite different in my area.  It refers to the words spoken by someone which leads to them getting punched.

Comment: Agreed, there are plenty of SW answers, as well as phrases and idioms.

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe no one suggested [**pricey**](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/pricey) yet.

> pric•ey /ˈpraɪsi/  also ˈpric•y, adj., -i•er, -i•est. 
>   too expensive: *those pricey cars.*
>
> expensive or unduly expensive: *a pricey wine.*

Comment: A mink coat is pricey, doesn't mean the person buying it has been ripped off. Likewise a good bottle of wine, some people are prepared to fork out an extra ten euros, while those who buy their wine in carton boxes (*shiver*) think paying anything above two euros is lavish spending. I usually hear something being "a bit pricey" or "steep",  suggesting the person would purchase it if it wasn't out of their comfort zone.

Answer (score 1):

Mugged off!... Stitched up... "He stitched me up on that bike, carbs are gone." or "My mate mugged me off on a deal"

Comment: Where are these expressions in use? I've never heard them, and I'm not sure I'd know what they meant without extensive context.

Comment: Very definitely British slang/colloquialisms. Popular here in some areas, but almost certainly unheard of outside of the UK

Comment: Funny, I would have assumed being "stitched up" would be a good thing. I mean, not that you'd need to be stitched up in the first place, but having a friend who could stitch you up if you needed it... sounds like a good friend to have (presumably he'd be a doctor.) Words are weird.

Comment: hi Martha, totally commonplace BrE

Answer (score 1):

***bumped***

When you get the raw end of a deal, you've been ***bumped***.

Comment: very nice idiom

Answer (score 1):

[racket](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=racket&allowed_in_frame=0)

> "loud noise," 1560s, perhaps imitative. Klein compares Gaelic *racaid* "noise." Meaning "dishonest activity" (1785) is perhaps from *racquet*, via notion of "game," reinforced by *rack-rent* "extortionate rent" (1590s), from *rack* …. But it might as well be an extended sense of "loud noise" by way of "**noise or disturbance made to distract a pick-pocket's victim**."

a fraudulent scheme, enterprise, or activity

e.g.

You won't believe the prices they are charging, and its the same all over town, so it must be some kind of *racket*.

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> "The price was so high that I **felt like I'd been robbed**."

Answer (score 1):

**Disproportionate**

> Out of proportion, not appropriate in respect of quantity, extent or degree. (OED)

Answer (score 0):

[stiff](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stiff&allowed_in_frame=0)

*v.*

Usually applied to describe "to fail or refuse to tip a server," to *stiff* also means more generally "to cheat someone out of money."

e.g.

You said your brother-in-law would give me a fair deal, so I was surprised that he would *stiff* me out of so much money.